# Drupal Views: find the term created by a NAT association

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I use NAT (Node Auto Term) to associate a content type with a vocabulary. Then I'm using that generated and sync'd vocabulary to create relationships with other content types. Within the Views UI, is there a method for finding that generated Term for any given Node? I've tried the "NAT: Nid" relationship, but that doesn't seem to return what I'm looking for.

Here's a little more detail:

I have two content types, Services ("parent") and Programs ("children"). Services has a NAT sync configured. Programs get "tagged" with terms from that generated Services vocabulary.

On my Services Node display, I'd like to write a view that lists the Programs that have been tagged with that Service. Within Views, I know the services.NID... but how do I find the corresponding TID so that I can find the related nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Never used NAT, but in your use case i'd rather use cck node reference.
On the other hand, have you tried posting a support request on the [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/nat?text=&status=All&priorities=All&categories=support&version=All&component=All) ?

Comment: I have other uses for the taxonomy terms beyond the use case I described; also, in my "hierarchy" a child can have multiple parents -- not a strict 1:1 relationship.

I'll check out the issue queue.